# Learning a new language project

Tags: programming-languages

Does anyone have a standard project that they use when learning a new language. Kinda like a specification document of a project that includes all aspects of programming. Does anyone use some sort of beginning type project when learning a new language? I guess it also depends on the type of language and what's it's capable of.

Comment: My personal route of learning any new language is: 1) read specification, 2) read a couple of examples, 3) implement a compiler for this language, work on it until all the examples works.

Comment: For a web-stack a usual "Hello World" project involves creating a blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the first few problems of [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is a very good way to get a handle on topics like I/O, recursion, iteration, and basic data structures.  I'd highly recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Contributing something to an open source project seems to work for me.  In addition to getting  exposed to some coding habits in the language , you get to work on something useful.

Comment: first code quality should be enough for opensource? ;)

Comment: There are always an army of opensourcers doing code review ... a bit of criticism will hurt but in the end its worth it....(not advisable if you are beginning programming though)

Comment: I'm not sure about the code review community, but the idea is nice.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine had a coworker who coded a minesweeper every time when he wanted to learn a new language with GUI.

Comment: For me it's boring a little I choose different tasks every time.

Answer (score 0):

I like making simple websites for learning.

Pro: you can put it online and show it to people.

Con: the language has to be suitable for web development.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a simple ray tracer:

- math functions (pow, sqrt, your own intersection routines)
- recursion (because it is a whitted style recursive one)
- iteration (for all pixels)
- how to write custom types (rays, possibly vectors)
- pixel wise graphics
- have something to play with compiler's (optimization-) flags

optional:

- simple GUI
- file reading writing

I've also done so with [metatrace](http://gitorious.org/metatrace).